# What is the best way to version control a multi app project?

Tags: git

I have a project which involves multiple apps.  The website includes all the apps and each app also has it's own cordova app.  The cordova apps are different in how they are set up (in comparison to the website) but some of the code they use is identical (app.js, app.css, etc).

Currently I use git and have 3 branches for local, alpha and beta versions of the website, which as I said includes all the apps.  Currently I copy/paste the code between each app on the website with each one's cordova counterpart. It is messy and will lead to a lot of issues, but I can't figure out how to do it better.  Can someone suggest a possible solution?

Comment: "I use git and have 3 branches for local, alpha and beta versions of the website."  I would suggest learning better git, which includes using branches for their intended purpose, and using tags.  *If I come across mean when saying this, I'm sorry.  I don't mean to be mean :)*.

Comment: No offence taken.  I realize what I am doing isn't the best way, i'm just trying to discover what the best way is.  But thanks for mentioning tags, I will do some research on them.

Comment: I don't want to submit this as an answer, but I would suggest having either separate repos or separate branches for each app.  Then, you can `git checkout` to the branch and `git pull` to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All-in-one repository vs repository-per-project isn't a "better" or "worse" thing, they have their pros and cons.  Generally speaking, if the projects are related (alterations of the same web site, for example), then you should probably leave them in a single repository.  You can always change your mind later.

> Currently I copy/paste the code between each app on the website with each one's cordova counterpart.

Since your apps are so related that you're copying code between them, you should keep them in a single repository. This allows you to make the same change across all projects in a single commit.

**NOTE**: Your real problem is not your Git layout but all that code copying.  You're creating a maintenance nightmare.  You should ask a question about how to handle that better.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping all of the projects in one repository is an easy way to keep them up to date with each other, however, it will likely cause you to have a messy history. I'm not sure about the core reasons that you are copying code between the applications, but in the ideal situation this code would be in a library and each application would be in its own repository. If you do put all of your applications in a single repository I would not recommend putting them on separate branches, as you will only be able to checkout one application at a time.

In regards to the branching system you are currently using it could be greatly improved using another system. One of the most popular systems is git-flow.

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

The essence of the git flow model is the use of master, release, develop, and feature branches (among others) to organise the state that your code is in. This could be seen as a more advanced version of your alpha, beta, and local branches.